# Objective C, iOS, What options are there to add some text on top of an image in an UIImageView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I need to add some numbers / text, programmatically so it shows on top of an image I have specified for several UIImageViews. Also my users are able to drag the image view around the screen. I need the text to move at the same time. To move the image views I use this code..

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

for (id football in multipleFootballs) {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == football) {
        CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:football];
        CGRect frame = [football frame];
        frame.origin.x += pt.x - startLocation.x;
        frame.origin.y += pt.y - startLocation.y;      
        [football setFrame:frame];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: as a UIImageView is a UIView you can add a UILabel as subview to it.

Comment: @Nick, I thought if that, do you mean to add a label for every image view in interface builder ? This just seems a bit messy.

Comment: No you've got to do it during runtime, it's not possible to add a subview with IB to a UIImageView.

Comment: @Nick, hmmm, i think I may have done something similar with custom cells in a table view. Think I just had to set the delate and add as a subview.

Comment: You are adding subviews all the time by using IB, however if you haven't done it programmatically give me a hint, I'll drop some code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just about any `UIView` or `UIView` descendent can be added to any other `UIView` as a subview. So you could create a `UILabel` with your text and add it as a subview to your `UIImageViews` using an appropriate `CGRect` for the `UILabel`'s frame to position it where you want it in your `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass UIImageview and add a UILabel as a subview. Then you can edit the label and it would work seamlessly.